# I accidentally clicked a button that deleted all commits made for a website, but I have a backup on my computer - how to restore?

Tags: git, github, restore

On the github website, it said something like "you are xx commits ahead and user2 is xx commits behind". I saw that for a long time and thought I had to do something to solve that. So I clicked it and it took my website back to where it was 8 months ago.

The place I clicked says "This branch is up to date with user/repository:main." when there are no commits. I don't remember exactly what it said before I clicked anymore.

I have a whole backup of the repository on my computer, and I use rstudio for it. However, when I try to "commit" or force push, there is nothing to click to commit and it also asks for my password and username, but then it says that this type of authentification is not supported anymore.

Not sure what to do.

Comment: "I clicked" can you explain what you clicked on ?

Comment: @LeGEC, I added some additional information. This text appears between the folders of the repository and the buttons to click branch, main etc. when you are on the main folder of your repository - the "home" of the repository where you can see your folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to open the shell.
2. Go into the backup folder (a real clone of the repository).
3. Issue the command `git push origin`.

**Edit: if you want to replace the remote repository with your backup copy (NO CLONE, NO COMMITS HISTORY!).**

```
                                                    ▒██         ███          
 █████░                                             █░            █      █   
 █   ▒█                                             █             █      █   
 █    █  ███           ▓██▒  ░███░   █▒██▒  ███   █████  █   █    █      █   
 █   ▒█ ▓▓ ▒█         ▓█  ▓  █▒ ▒█   ██  █ ▓▓ ▒█    █    █   █    █      █   
 █████░ █   █         █░         █   █     █   █    █    █   █    █      █   
 █   ▒█ █████         █      ▒████   █     █████    █    █   █    █      █   
 █    █ █             █░     █▒  █   █     █        █    █   █    █          
 █   ▒█ ▓▓  █         ▓█  ▓  █░ ▓█   █     ▓▓  █    █    █▒ ▓█    █░     █   
 █████░  ███▒          ▓██▒  ▒██▒█   █      ███▒    █    ▒██▒█    ▒██    █
```

1. Open the shell.
2. Go into the backup folder
3. `git init`.
4. `git remote add origin <REMOTE_REPOSITORY_URL>`.
5. `git add --all`.
6. `git commit -m "Whole replacement commit."`.
7. **Replace remote repository by:** `git push --force`.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm not sure if the backup folder is technically a real clone. I was having some issues with pushing and committing, and a reason why could be that it wasn't properly set up as a clone.
By shell, do you mean the terminal in rstudio?

Comment: It is not a clone you cannot recover your commits. :(

Comment: I don't care about the commits really. I just want to replace the repository on github with my folder on my computer. Anyway I can push everything and make one big commit?

Comment: Sure, I will edit my post for this...

Comment: It completely worked, and all the commits are actually there again now. The button I clicked was: This branch is 166 commits ahead of, 96 commits behind xxx. Cause the branch had conflicts: "This branch has conflicts that must be resolved
Discard 166 commits to make this branch match the upstream repository. 166 commits will be removed from this branch.

You can resolve merge conflicts using the command line and a text editor."

Comment: Did you issue the first solution?

Comment: I used the second solution.